# Table cell element ignoring width in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I have been successfully able to highlight the correct cells with a selector.  However the `width` tag is being ignored.  Can someone explain why the widths of the cells aren't affected?

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZfbp/1/).

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Title</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test Title</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="middle">
<table border="1" width="100%">     
    <tr>
        <th>Test Col 1</th>
        <th>Test Col 2</th>
        <th>Test Col 3</th>
        <th>Test Col 4</th>
        <th>Test Col 5</th>
        <th>Test Col 6</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Col 1</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
        <td>Col 5</td>
        <td>Col 6</td>
     </tr>
     </table>
</div>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>LINKS</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LINK 1  | LINK 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LINK 1  | LINK 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table { float:left; }
.middle {  float:left; width:350px; overflow:auto;}
.middle table td, .middle table th { width:300px; background:red; }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add `table-layout:fixed` to your table CSS:

```
table { float:left;table-layout:fixed; }
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uZfbp/2/)**

Answer (score 6):

*width* property of *td* and *th* elements is not supported at HTML5, still you can get a workaround by setting their display to inline-block and setting their width via CSS.

Comment: can you add a source for that claim?

Comment: Are you confusing that with the width _attribute_?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your table-layout algorithm to `fixed` in place of the default value, `auto`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/uZfbp/3/)

More info from the [W3C](http://w3.org) regarding the `fixed` table-layout value:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout

Comment: table style="table-layout:fixed;width:600px"
Yet my table is drawn as 605px.

I come from a Windows programming background where you specify the width you want and you get the width you want.
With CSS you specify the width you want and you get something else.
If Microsoft made CSS everyone would be disparaging them for how bad it is but the www consortium get let off easy.

Comment: @Paul: Actually Microsoft tried to do exactly that in 1999 or 2000 when they released either IE 5 or IE 5.5, because what you describe is the exact box model they used. They thought theirs was better than the W3C standard model, and tried to force it on everyone by just releasing their browser with only their box model. As everyone was sick of this sort of behavior by them around this time, they were unsuccessful, and were forced to invent DocType tags to allow the user to specify which box model to use. This support for two different box models made IE6 perhaps the buggiest browser in history

Comment: Then they made two really painful decisions for web designers, one was to clamp down hard on piracy in a way that made it so hundreds of millions of pirated copies of Windows XP never got upgraded to IE7, which fixed most of these bugs, and they released Windows Vista, which everyone hated for the first 5 years. Between these two decisions, and this seemingly innocent attempt to act as benevolent dictators with their more intuitive proprietary browser box model, IE6 had significant market share for 10+ years longer than it should have, setting back web design by 15 years

Comment: How were they unable to convince the W3C that giving the designer the width they specify was better? Maybe that rocket that crashed into the moon was using CSS to calculate the distance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width:350px;` from `.middle`  You are setting the width of the table and then expecting the cells to be able to fill up more space then allotted.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do. I want the middle table to scroll