# Some images appearing distorted in table (when re-sizing for mobile) despite being the same size

Tags: css, html, html-table

Having some immense trouble/confusion with a table I'm currently working on, as logically I feel like everything should be displaying evenly in their table elements as all table rows/columns should have even spacing, and all the images are the exact same size but some are appearing distorted and I have no idea what's causing it.

Here's the source for the current table:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Title of Program &amp; Status</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Emerging Leaders</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Middle Leaders</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Established Leaders</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Aspirant Leaders</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Initial Leaders</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Experienced Leaders</font></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><font style="font-size:1vw;">Mentor Principals</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle">
        <p style="font-size:1vw;">Leadership Masterclass</p>

        <p style="font-size:1vw;">A program to introduce a growth coaching approach to conversational contexts in schools.</p>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/a185933e-7199-497a-912e-a424060c8b39/button_orange.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/6e2316cc-1e14-46f9-8f28-a821bf3eea46/Button_pink.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/969ab310-1d1b-4cf7-9643-e83f78f70aeb/button_purple.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/59634623-1879-4dc1-b056-01b98e067a64/button_green.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/32abc54e-c1da-4f89-acbc-6ac3c9b800aa/button_red.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/0ed3d516-d829-46f0-abb0-2af57b07b298/button_yellow.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
        <td align="center" style="width: 10%;" valign="middle"><img alt="" src="/getmedia/4ec07bbf-aee6-4626-9c75-8fed16f90a00/button_blue.aspx?" width="35vw" height="35vh" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here's an image of how it's currently displaying:
[image of mobile re-sized table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTPbx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table columns are being resized to fit their biggest element.... which is in this case the headings. Your heading length is driving your column width which is driving your image size.

Width in td's is by default ignored: [<TD> tag ignoring width in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422499/td-tag-ignoring-width-in-css)